# Python: Reading lines in a text file and counting instances where lines directly below are identical

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, counter

I'm new to Python and looking for some help.
I have a large text file that I want to search and count the amount of times a line is identical to the one above it. Here is what I have so far.

```
f = open('test.txt')

counter = 0

for line in f:
    nextline = f.next()

    if line == nextline:
        counter = counter + 1
print counter
f.close()
```

This groups and compares the first and second line, then the third and the fourth and so on. How can I adjust the program to compare the first line with the second, then the second with the third, the third with the fourth etc.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So if you have `line1 line1 line1 line2 line2 line3`, is the answer 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference of the PREVIOUS line like this:

```
f = open('test.txt') 

counter = 0 
prevLine = None

for line in f: 
    if line == prevLine: 
        counter = counter + 1
    prevLine = line 

print counter 
f.close()
```

Comment: I would not initialize it with the empty string: it is possible the first line in the file is an empty string as well.

Comment: In Python that is `None`, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `f.next()` you will already advance to the next line. You can however use a variable `old_line` that stores the previous line. Each time at the end of the loop, you set `old_line` to refer to `line`. Furthermore you set `old_line` initially to `None` to ensure the first line is not counted.

```
counter = 0
with open('test.txt') as f:
    old_line = None
    for line in f:
        if line == old_line:
            counter += 1
        old_line = line
print counter
```

Comment: @Coldspeed: the question says: "*How can I adjust the program to compare the first line with the second, then the second with the third, the third with the fourth etc.*". I don't see anything about incrementing the same line only once.

Comment: Yeah I probably misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be one strange solution ... and here you are

```
from functools import reduce #if you are useing Python 3+

count = 0
def compare_string(prev, new):
    global count
    if prev == new:
        count += 1
    return new

with open('test.txt') as f:
    reduce(compare_sring, f)
```

Comment: @vZ10: you can use `nonlocal`. But `global` makes it "global". Global variables are bad design.

Comment: @Coldspeed: no it is not strange: if you do an assignment (and `+=` is an assignment), then the variable is treated as a local one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = open('filename.txt').read().splitlines()

print len([f[i] for i in range(len(f)-1) if f[i] == f[i+1]])
```

Comment: You can do `(1 for i in ...)` to save space.

Comment: True, but I thought that the OP may also want to see which lines are identical, not just count them as well.